# Split/push string as array

Tags: javascript

I have a string separated by '-'  and need to convert it into an array. I tried splitting it, but it's not working out.

```js
avgCreditUsage('[1, 72]-[2, 79]-[3, 81]-[4, 76]-[5, 93]-[6, 81]-[7, 85]-[8, 66]-[9, 66]-[10, 72]-[11, 67]-[12, 72]-[13, 71]-[14, 80]-[15, 94]-[16, 56]-[17, 61]-[18, 81]-[19, 82]-[20, 64]-[21, 74]-[22, 77]-[23, 96]-[24, 83]-[25, 91]-[26, 85]-[27, 72]-[28, 80]-[29, 74]-[30, 70]-[31, 86]');

function avgCreditUsage(creditsPerDOM) {

    /*
 * LINE CHART
 * ----------
 */
    //var sin = [
    //     [gd(2012, 0, 1), 1652.21], [gd(2012, 1, 1), 1742.14], [gd(2012, 2, 1), 1673.77], [gd(2012, 3, 1), 1649.69],
    //     [gd(2012, 4, 1), 1591.19], [gd(2012, 5, 1), 1598.76], [gd(2012, 6, 1), 1589.90], [gd(2012, 7, 1), 1630.31],
    //     [gd(2012, 8, 1), 1744.81], [gd(2012, 9, 1), 1746.58], [gd(2012, 10, 1), 1721.64], [gd(2012, 11, 2), 1684.76]
    //    ]

    var array = creditsPerDOM.split("-");
    var sin = [array];

    var line_data1 = {
        data: sin,
        color: "#00c0ef"
    };
    $.plot("#line-chart", [line_data1], {
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            borderColor: "#f3f3f3",
            borderWidth: 1,
            tickColor: "#f3f3f3"
        },
        series: {
            shadowSize: 0,
            lines: {
                show: true
            },
            points: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        lines: {
            fill: false,
            color: ["#3c8dbc", "#f56954"]
        },
        yaxis: {
            show: true,
        },
        xaxis: {
            show: true
        }
    });
    //Initialize tooltip on hover
    $('<div class="tooltip-inner" id="line-chart-tooltip"></div>').css({
        position: "absolute",
        display: "none",
        opacity: 0.8
    }).appendTo("body");
    $("#line-chart").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

        if (item) {
            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

            $("#line-chart-tooltip").html(item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y)
                .css({ top: item.pageY + 5, left: item.pageX + 5 })
                .fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $("#line-chart-tooltip").hide();
        }

    });
    /* END LINE CHART */

}
```

Comment: Firstly note that this has nothing to do with jQuery; it's pure Javascript. Secondly, your code works fine, as you can see in the snippet I edited in to your question. If the output is not what you expect, please give us details of what you require

Comment: Uhhh, `string.split(...)` returns an array.  What are you expecting?

Comment: It does return an array, however it's not displaying the line chart. I'll edit my question now to contain the full code

Comment: @Orion Can you please provide a link to the jQuery plot library you are using? That we'll need to know how the API works / what format the plot expects.

Comment: @ContinuousLoad This is the plot lib https://github.com/flot/flot The format is exactly as the string value I'm parsing. It works when I hard code it into the array. Only not working when I'm generating it server side and sending it back as a result. Just to note, the string value I have in my question is from the result sent back from server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to @Taplar's JSON aproach (which is the fastest of all the answers listed here, according to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/4557z/)), but it converts each individual item.

This approach favors readability over performance.

```js
var creditsPerDOM = '[1, 72]-[2, 79]-[3, 81]-[4, 76]-[5, 93]-[6, 81]-[7, 85]-[8, 66]-[9, 66]-[10, 72]-[11, 67]-[12, 72]-[13, 71]-[14, 80]-[15, 94]-[16, 56]-[17, 61]-[18, 81]-[19, 82]-[20, 64]-[21, 74]-[22, 77]-[23, 96]-[24, 83]-[25, 91]-[26, 85]-[27, 72]-[28, 80]-[29, 74]-[30, 70]-[31, 86]';

var dataSeries = creditsPerDOM.split('-').map(JSON.parse);

console.log(dataSeries);
```

If I understand correctly,

```
$.plot('#line-chart', [dataSeries] ... )
```

Comment: Please see edited question. I tried your approach and it's still not displaying the graph though.

Comment: That's partially correct. Your code works now after I edited my code with your solution as follows:

var dataSeries = creditsPerDOM.split('-').map(JSON.parse);
var line_data1 = {
            data: dataSeries,
            color: "#00c0ef"
        };
        $.plot("#line-chart", [line_data1], {..

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to json format and then use the parse method.

```js
var creditsPerDOM = '[1, 72]-[2, 79]-[3, 81]-[4, 76]-[5, 93]-[6, 81]-[7, 85]-[8, 66]-[9, 66]-[10, 72]-[11, 67]-[12, 72]-[13, 71]-[14, 80]-[15, 94]-[16, 56]-[17, 61]-[18, 81]-[19, 82]-[20, 64]-[21, 74]-[22, 77]-[23, 96]-[24, 83]-[25, 91]-[26, 85]-[27, 72]-[28, 80]-[29, 74]-[30, 70]-[31, 86]';

var array = JSON.parse('['+ creditsPerDOM.split("-").join(",") +']');

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Please see edited question. I tried your approach and it's still not displaying the graph though.

Comment: This solution is 74% faster than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit the JSON-like format of your string

```
var creditsPerDOM = '[1, 72]-[2, 79]-[3, 81]-[4, 76]-[5, 93]-[6, 81]-[7, 85]-[8, 66]-[9, 66]-[10, 72]-[11, 67]-[12, 72]-[13, 71]-[14, 80]-[15, 94]-[16, 56]-[17, 61]-[18, 81]-[19, 82]-[20, 64]-[21, 74]-[22, 77]-[23, 96]-[24, 83]-[25, 91]-[26, 85]-[27, 72]-[28, 80]-[29, 74]-[30, 70]-[31, 86]';

 var all = creditsPerDOM.split(-);

 var final = [];

 all.forEach(function(miniArray){
      var arr = JSON.parse(miniArray);   // [x, y]
      final.push(miniArray[0]);
      final.push(miniArray[1]);  
 })
```

Comment: Did not work for me :( Please see my edited question with full code